# Rails: How to customise the order of fields in a form with nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, nested-attributes, fields-for

I have a form that saves attributes to two models `Company` and nested model `Address` in a single form using `simple_nested_form_for` and `simple_fields_for`.

The attributes:

```
Company:
-legal form
-uploads

Address:
-name
-website
```

In my form I wish to change the order of the fields

```
-name (Address model)
-legal form (Company model)
-website (Address model)
-uploads (Company model)
```

thus **interchanging** the `form` attributes and `nested_field` attributes

I tried the following, but that did not seem to work.

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @company do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |c| %>
        <%= c.input :name %> 
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :legal_form %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |c| %>
        <%= c.input :website %> 
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :uploads %>
<% end %>
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it doesn't look like all your attributes line up ( you said uploads was address and website was in company in your attributes list but the form doesn't match that ) there is still a simple solution to your question.

Nested fields rely on their builder to denote which part of the params hash to put them in.  So simply call the builder that you need.

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @company do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |c| %>
    <%= c.input :name %> 
    <%= f.input :legal_form %>
    <%= c.input :website %> 
    <%= f.input :uploads %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In each place that you need the company fields, you'll call builder `f` and in each place you need the address fields, you'll call builder `c` - but nested them all inside the lowest common denominator so they're all available.

Comment: That's an excellent answer. I was looking for exactly this. (sorry for the error in ordering). Cheers, M